# Hiding error message in Node.js&Express from POST access

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running a Restful API Server based on Node.js using Express.js.

Today, I realized that someone can get information of error of my source code, including directory path of my server, when he send request using Curl like `curl -X POST ~`.

Error message I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
>       at exports.list (/usr/local/node/XXX/routes/message.js:49:36)
>       at callbacks (/usr/local/node/XXX/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:124:37)
>       at param (/usr/local/node/XXX/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:118:11)
>       at param (/usr/local/node/XXXv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:125:11)

How can I hide those critical information when the server displays errors?

Comment: You must handle the errors carefully, I do not think there is any other options. You might wanna consider promises which helps not only for async process but also handling errors.

Comment: mind removing the django-rest-framework flag as it's totally unrelated ?

Answer (score 7):

I'd set the `NODE_ENV` flag to `production`, as the Express.JS doesn't send the stack data in this mode. I recommend you to check out the [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) module in npm.

Answer (score 3):

> If you pass an error to `next()` and you do not handle it in a custom error handler, it will be handled by **the built-in error handler**; the error will be written to the client with the stack trace. **The stack trace is not included in the production environment.**
>
> https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Set your environment variable `NODE_ENV` to `production` when running Node.js to suppress stack traces. It’ll still be shown on the console.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a middleware that deals with all unhandled errors for you.

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.sendStatus(500);
  }
  next();
});
```

That will return a 500 Internal Server Error status code to any user creating such an error. Remember to put this at the end of your middleware chain.

Answer (score 0):

Just send them this kind of response if you don't want to send any message

```
res.sendStatus(500);
```

or you can use errorhandler in your express setting like this if you want to send stacktrace as well

```
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
    .....//define app as express object
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      // only use in development 
      app.use(errorhandler())
    }
```

Comment: Sadly, errorhandler does strictly nothing. The log function is not called, and we still can't see any stack traces in dev.